# Cheap way for daily commuting in Japan

Tags: japan, commute

I leave in Greece and in the next year I am planning to go for PhD studies in Japan under MEXT scholarship. So I am in search for expense management whilst leaving there.

As far as I heard of public means of transport and rents in Japan are in the roof compared to the rents in Greece. So I was thinking of instead of using public means of transport instead to use a 50cc motorbike for daily commute between home and university and back.

But I want to know if this is a good idea. The particular scooter I am thinking is the Honda Supercub because is cheap on maintenance. Is the small engine motorbike recommended for daily commuting in Japan?

My goal is to save money whilst staying in Japan over extended period of time (I estimate about 2~5 yrs).

Comment: You might be interested in [/r/movingtojapan](http://reddit.com/r/movingtojapan) on Reddit.

Comment: As a postdoc at a Japanese university: yes, in general that will work (but note that you will have to get the appropriate licence which may or may not involve doing a test in Japanese in Japan). However, as a student you *should* be entitled to cheaper tickets of some sort and often you will live within walking distance of your campus.

Comment: I was a former MEXT scholar (1995-1999) and if the rules have not changed, we were prohibited from driving for safety reasons. Also, don't worry about commuting cost and rent - the monthly stipend that you will be receive will be more than enough to cover those expenses. Also cheap housing will be provided to you. Your goal should be to focus on your studies, learn as much as you can about the language and culture, and make friends. Saving money should not be a goal, just a result.